# Using native javascript have a html onclick change text to uppercase as you type

Tags: javascript, html

I an creating a project where people can create posts.  I have a text editor I'm creating for this section.  I need to make text uppercase if user clicks a button.  All these other buttons work with execommand but there isnt an option for uppercase.  My question is there an alternative I can use to do this?

Javascript

```
 function headBold() {
 document.execCommand('styleWithCSS', false, true);
 document.execCommand('bold',false,null);}
 function headItalics() {
 document.execCommand('styleWithCSS', false, true);
 document.execCommand('italic',false,null);}
 function headUndLne() {
 document.execCommand('styleWithCSS', false, true);
 document.execCommand('underline',false,null);}
 function headuppercase() {   }
```

HTML

```
<button type="button" onclick="headBold();" class="bolden">B</button>
<button type="button" onclick="headItalics();" class="italics"><i>I</i></button>
<button type="button" onclick="headUndLne();" class="underline">U</button>
<button type="button" onclick="headuppercase();" class="upperCase">Tt</button>
```

This is being used in a content editable div not an input.
Please no JQuery.
The effect I'm looking for is the same one in CSS.

```
font-variant: small-caps;
```

Comment: You wanted the selected text to have the desired effect?

Comment: yes the same as CSS font-variant: small-caps produces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no command identifier for [`font-variant:small-caps`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-variant). The demo is solution that'll compliment an editor such as yours, but it doesn't use [`execCommand`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand) but it performs exactly like one.

**function tags(*tag*, *klass*)**

Usage: Select some text, then call `tags("span", "sC")`

- Creates a *tag* with the specified *clas*s from the required parameters.
- Uses the [Range](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range) and [Selection API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection) to wrap the dynamically created tag ***around*** the selected text.

Result: `<span class="sC">`Sᴏᴍᴇ Tᴇ𝘅ᴛ`</span>`

```js
function setB() {
  document.execCommand('bold', false, null);
}

function setI() {
  document.execCommand('italic', false, null);
}

function setU() {
  document.execCommand('underline', false, null);
}

function setsC(e) {
  tags('span', 'sC');
}

function tags(tag, klass) {
  var ele = document.createElement(tag);
  ele.classList.add(klass);
  wrap(ele);
}  

function wrap(tags) {
  var select = window.getSelection();
  if (select.rangeCount) {
    var range = select.getRangeAt(0).cloneRange();
    range.surroundContents(tags);
    select.removeAllRanges();
    select.addRange(range);
  }
}
```

```css
#editor {
  min-height: 100px;
  width: 80%;
  border:4px inset grey;
  padding:3px 5px;
}

.sC {
  font-variant: small-caps
}
```

```html
<section id='editor' contenteditable='true'></section>
<button type="button" onclick="setB();" class="bd"><b>B</b></button>
<button type="button" onclick="setI();" class="it"><i>I</i></button>
<button type="button" onclick="setU();" class="uL"><u>U</u></button>
<button type="button" onclick="setsC();" class="sC">Tt</button>
```

Comment: How do you save the markdown of the newly stylized text? Like if I want to reload all my edits later? Is there a property that contains `<b>text</b>`?

Comment: SO markdown editors accept some phasing elements like: `<b>` (or **), `<i>` (or *), `<sup>`, `<kbd>`,  etc., [HTML entities](http://www.amp-what.com/unicode/search/%2F%26%5Cw%2F) are also accepted. See this [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: How can you use this to toggle the class on and off depending on the selected range?

Comment: @msqar Try changing this line: `ele.classList.add(klass);` to this line: `ele.classList.toggle(klass);`

Comment: Will this toggle the class to the entire node/selected node? I'm implementing a summernote plugin where you can add style text-transform: uppercase or lowercase and of course, be able to toggle it to a selected node. But i notice in my implementation that is kinda based on yours that i keep creating new nodes and wrapping them around with the old node as the parent.

Comment: @msqar I have an answer that resolves nested wraps [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55411995/2813224). If you need help implementing it, as the answer is agnostic and may need further augmentation to cooperate with a plugin, you'll need to post a separate question and reference this and/or the other question/answer. On the other hand, if any answer/question helps resolve your problem remember to upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

Create a function where you get the input you are trying to transform the text to uppercase to:

```
var headUpperCase = function(){
   var inputValue = document.getElementById("your-input").value;
   inputValue = inputValue.toUpperCase();
}
```

and then

```
<button type="button" onclick="headuppercase();" class="upperCase">Tt</button>
```

Comment: This is being used in a content editable div not an input.  I cant get it to work.

Comment: it needs to be in real time.  If you click the button it activates uppercase as you type if you click it again it deactivates while you type.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `text-transform:uppercase;`, it will make the inner text of the div capitalized.

```
function makeUpperCase() {
  var contentDiv = window.document.getElementById("editable-container");
  var contentDivTextTransform = contentDiv.style.textTransform;
  if(contentDivTextTransform === "uppercase") {
    contentDiv.style.textTransform = "";
  } else {
    contentDiv.style.textTransform = "uppercase";  
  }  
}
```

[Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jchaplin2/n93pefdg/1/)