# Overwrite highlighted text on mouseup text selection+ HTML5/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, highlight, textselection

I have some content generated by a ML model in 100s of paragraphs, each para has some highlighted content.

**Sometimes, highlighted data is incorrect, we want the user to select the text and get it highlighted again to correct it.**

```
<p> Contrary to popular belief, <span class='highlighted'>Lorem</span>Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of popular classical Latin literature from 45 <span class='highlighted'>BC</span>, making it over 2000 years old.</p>
```

In this example, the user might want to select:

1. Lorem Ipsum
2. Latin
3. 45 BC
4. 2000 years

Below code works for #2 and #4, but I am not able to do it for #1 and #3 as its already highlighted.

I am using this function [getSelectionText()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5379120/get-the-highlighted-selected-text)  to select the text.

```
$('div.content>p').on('mouseup', function(e){
    var toselected = getSelectionText();
    var para = $(this).html();
    var start = para.indexOf(toselected);
    var end = start + toselected.length;
    var html = para.replace(toselected, '<span class="highlighted">' toselected + '</span>');
    var obj = {"content": $(this).text(), "indices_range":[[start, end]]}
    $.post('/update/<content_id>', data:tojson(obj), function(){        $(e.target).html(html);}) 

});
```

Also wondering, how can I get the start, end indices if same text occurs twice or multiple times eg. `popular`.?

Comment: You  want the user to be able to unhighlight something previously highlighted?

Comment: "Sometimes, highlighted data is incorrect, we want the user to select the text and get it highlighted."

Comment: @zer00ne - Indirectly yes, unhighlight highlighted if highlighted is selected, and highlight the entire correct word/phrase.

Comment: I was creating something similiar and to fully restore / set selection. First every html element have in my code unique id. I set contenteditable to true and for selected text I set background color and turn off contenteditable. parameters to do it startOffset endOffset startID, endID - to correctly restore selection. range.setStart(el, offset); range.setEnd(el, offset); see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/range/setStart

Answer (score 1):

Use [Range](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range) and [Selection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection) APIs to control selection of text nodes. Instead of using `<span>`, use `<mark>` tags. 
**Reasons to use [`<mark>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/mark)**

- 100% semantic
- It's use is uncommon which means there's very little chance of CSS selector conflicts.
- By default it already highlights it's content.

**Usage:** Highlight text with mouse like you would normally. The `<mark>s` do not nest (that's a good thing). In order to remove a highlighted area, click it using the right mouse button.

```js
const mark = event => {
  const current = event.currentTarget;
  const target = event.target;
  const select = document.getSelection();
  if (event.which === 1) {
    const range = select.getRangeAt(0);
    const text = range.toString();
    const content = range.extractContents();
    const mark = document.createElement('MARK');
    mark.textContent = text;
    range.insertNode(mark);
  } else if (event.which === 3) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (target.tagName === 'MARK') {
      const text = target.textContent;
      const tNode = document.createTextNode(text);
      target.parentNode.replaceChild(tNode, target);
    }
  }
  select.removeAllRanges();
  current.normalize();
  return false;
}

$(document).on("contextmenu mouseup", mark);
```

```css
::selection {
  background: tomato;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<p> Contrary to popular belief, <mark>Lorem</mark>Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of popular classical Latin literature from 45 <mark>BC</mark>, making it over 2000 years old.</p>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```